# expression not matching regex

Tags: php, regex, linux, grep

*grep (GNU grep) 2.16*

given the following string: *It's pretty late but I wanna regexp_ _this !*

`grep '[a-zA-Z]+'` hits everything but `'`, `_` and `!` characters (ok)

but `grep '[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*'` hits nothing (in my example `regexp_` should match, but not `_this` (nok)

to sum up, I need to forbid words beginning with something else than a letter, and then allow alphanum & '_' character (0 or more time(s))

I've tried on https://regex101.com, both regexp work as expexted.
Only in my bash shell (as well as in php code I'm writing), the second regexp hits nothing.

**EDIT** : @anubhava #1 solution works fine.
I nevertheless want to do it via php code : `preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]\+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/',$myString)` doesn't work...

**RE-EDIT** : I misunderstood the use of PHP preg_match, sorry

Comment: Use `grep '[a-zA-Z]\+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*'` OR `grep -E '[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*'`

Comment: How are you using `grep`? It typically works on a line-by-line basis, so won't "hit" specific characters.

Comment: @anubhava ok thx, I wonder why I should escape + and not * then ?...

Comment: @miken32 probably not the right term... I meant string match pattern, and the 'reverse' : patterns 'hits' strings

Comment: `grep` uses BRE where `+` needs to be escaped unless you use `-E` (extended regex)

Comment: Doesn't this suffice `[a-zA-Z][\w_]*`? Or with case-insensitivity: `[a-z][\w_]*`?

Comment: I read \w actually includes underscore (in addition to alphanum)... I havn't tested your solution but thx :)

Comment: `\w` does include underscore, most UNIX tools won't support it, and those that do wouldn't recognize it inside a bracket expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've create a dummy-file with the content:

```
regexp_
asdf
_this
R_
```

the bash command (I've added the ^):

```
grep '^[a-zA-Z]\+[a-zA-Z0-9_]' dummy
```

gave me the result:

```
regexp_
asdf
R_
```

In PHP the regex needs to look like this (I've added the ^ and removed the \ before the +):

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/',$myString);
```

I hope that's what you needed.